# PHP Mail Postfix

Tags: postfix-mta, php

I have a PHP program using the `mail()` function.  I have this running on a Linux server.  Normally it is setup to run over the Linux sendmail function but my machine is setup to use Postfix.

Can I use the PHP mail function over postfix and if so does anyone know how to make that work?

Comment: PHP's mail will use whatever mailer is installed. Postfix provides a 'sendmail' compatibility executable (basically 'sendmail' is hardlined to 'postfix') so any app which is sendmail-aware will work without modification with postfix.

Comment: @MarcB okay so to get sendmail setup I had to edit the php.ini file to un-comment the line giving the path showing where to find sendmail.  Would it be the same path to use postfix?

Comment: `whereis sendmail` should tell you which path to use. And if you look at the sendmail that command returns, you'll find it's a symlink (or maybe a hardlink) pointing at `postfix`.

Comment: It might be a symlink pointing to something like /etc/alternatives/mta (IE on RHEL 6 and probably Fedora)

Answer (score 0):

`mail()` uses script given in php.ini file - "sendmail_path".

If You want to change it, you need to change "sendmail_path" in php.ini or script itself.

Answer (score 0):

try to revise this in `php.ini`:

```
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path = /etc/postfix
```